# Issue with sounds volume in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04

I've been having this problem for a few days now since I overriden my windows installation with Ubuntu for a fresh restart:

Basically, whenever I listen to music or a video on YouTube or any other site (Twitter, for example), the volume keeps going up and down randomly! The sliders are not moving on their own, but the heard volume keeps fluctuating. I've tried every single solution I've came across on the internet, but nothing have fixed it, you are my last chance of trying to fix this issue...

Thank you so much and have a good day/night!

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe the computer information you use below?

Although I haven't encountered a similar situation, it is most likely caused by the hardware mismatch with the linux kernel.

My computer can't use bluetooth properly due to using realtek's wireless card. After I replaced the Intel AX210, the network problem was solved.

You can try to find your audio device with the following command

```
lspci | grep -i audio
```